Model is still running even though optimization is done using Pyomo and Couenne as solver
I am using Couenne solver in Pyomo to run my optimization model. It has generated these results, but the model has been running for an hour and the details (instance.display) are not shown yet.
Is there a code I am missing to display the decision variables? Or is the model still not done in its calculation yet and how much longer should I wait?
Results:
Clp0032I Optimal objective 4317.525521 - 80919 iterations time 48.642, Presolve 0.22
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 4317.5341
NLP Heuristic: no solution.
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 4317.5341

Code:
instance = md.create_instance(data)
solver_name = "couenne"
opt = pyo.SolverFactory(solver_name+"nl", executable=modules.find(solver_name), solve_io="nl")
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True)
instance.display()


Is it possible to write the solve status to see if the optimality condition is reached?

The optimality messages from Clp are for sub problems, not for the main MINLP problem. So Couenne may still be running. Try a small problem first.
